# Intercept WKWebView access to local file

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, file-access

I have a WKWebView in my app that displays a map. It is possible to add local tiles to this map, i.e. satellite images. This local tiles are located in the document folder of my app.

Now I need to intercept when the WKWebView loads one of those files, so I can use an image from another source.

Already tried a CustomSchemeHandler() with the Scheme `file:///` but because that is not a valid URL, it does not work. Also the `decidePolicyFor navigationAction` method is not called when loading the images.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Local tiles means, when tapping on annotations, you want to show satellite image?

Comment: There are no annotations to tab. But my map component shows satellite images. But when it accesses these images I want to intercept the access.

Comment: can you please add the code from your view/ViewController to get more information?